# square connect - object id in catalog update webhook notifications

Tags: square-connect

I've got the catalog update webhook going and I get the object id from the json message -- but it's a UUID type string vs. the standard all-caps object ID in the catalog API.  How do I exchange the UUID for a catalog object id in the API?  and how come when I update one of my items via the Square dashboard, the object id UUID string is different every time?

Using the Square webhooks page, I'm doing a test of the catalog update webhook and it says it's sending this to my website:

```
{
  "merchant_id": "6SSxxxxxxxST5",
  "type": "catalog.version.updated",
  "event_id": "f3f15f71-b6ef-46aa-b144-2dcf71b685ce",
  "created_at": "2020-07-15T02:21:19.950514042Z",
  "data": {
    "type": "catalog",
    "id": "732b6677-1acb-4d81-b09c-5a3a49399d8f",
    "object": {
      "catalog_version": {
        "updated_at": "2019-10-29T17:26:16.53Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I was going to use the data/id value to make a call to the "retrieve catalog object" API --

```
curl https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/object/W62UWFY35CWMYGVWK6TWJDNI?include_related_objects=true
```

But that example on their API page has the all-caps, full alphabet ID format.  Not the UUID multi-part hex format.  And I've used that API call -- like when doing a catalog search, you get back object IDs and such and then can retrieve using those for more information.

Which API can I call to find out which object in the catalog was updated?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can provide example of the code you already have

Comment: sorry - yes. I've added more detail.  not much code to show really -- just tests and samples from Square's site

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling that the Catalog *Version* Update webhook is a quickie ping that lets you know that the catalog was changed somehow and that if you want update your database or app, you need to re-sync all objects in which you are interested.  The UUID has no discernable meaning.